# Combining java objects in an arraylist

Tags: java, object, arraylist

So I have a temp arraylist of LeaderBoard objects(seen below) and I want to combine all of the gamertags with the same game name together into a new arraylist. How would I go about doing this?

```
LeaderBoard [win=0, lose=1, gameName=QUFI, gamerTag=Ithroeann, platform=IO], 
LeaderBoard [win=1, lose=0, gameName=QUFI, gamerTag=Ithroeann, platform=IO], 
LeaderBoard [win=1, lose=0, gameName=CODE, gamerTag=Cirronith, platform=PS], 
LeaderBoard [win=1, lose=0, gameName=CODE, gamerTag=Cirronith, platform=PS], 
LeaderBoard [win=1, lose=0, gameName=QUFI, gamerTag=Deathstar, platform=IO], 
LeaderBoard [win=1, lose=0, gameName=QUFI, gamerTag=Deathstar, platform=IO], 
LeaderBoard [win=0, lose=1, gameName=QUFI, gamerTag=Deathstar, platform=IO], 
LeaderBoard [win=0, lose=1, gameName=CODE, gamerTag=Mazzzap, platform=AN], 
LeaderBoard [win=0, lose=1, gameName=NUPI, gamerTag=Mazzzap, platform=AN], 
LeaderBoard [win=1, lose=0, gameName=QUFI, gamerTag=Mazzzap, platform=AN], 
LeaderBoard [win=1, lose=0, gameName=QUFI, gamerTag=Redstripe, platform=PC], 
LeaderBoard [win=0, lose=1, gameName=CODE, gamerTag=Redstripe, platform=PC], 
LeaderBoard [win=1, lose=0, gameName=NUPI, gamerTag=Redstripe, platform=PC], 
LeaderBoard [win=1, lose=0, gameName=CODE, gamerTag=Redstripe, platform=PC], 
LeaderBoard [win=1, lose=0, gameName=QUFI, gamerTag=Crayonbreath, platform=PS], 
LeaderBoard [win=1, lose=0, gameName=CODE, gamerTag=Quinesia, platform=XB], 
LeaderBoard [win=1, lose=0, gameName=NUPI, gamerTag=Quinesia, platform=XB], 
LeaderBoard [win=0, lose=1, gameName=QUFI, gamerTag=VolcanoBrawler, platform=PC], 
LeaderBoard [win=0, lose=1, gameName=NUPI, gamerTag=VolcanoBrawler, platform=PC], 
LeaderBoard [win=0, lose=1, gameName=NUPI, gamerTag=VolcanoBrawler, platform=PC], 
LeaderBoard [win=0, lose=1, gameName=CODE, gamerTag=VolcanoBrawler, platform=PC], 
LeaderBoard [win=0, lose=1, gameName=QUFI, gamerTag=CastleRock, platform=XB], 
LeaderBoard [win=1, lose=0, gameName=NUPI, gamerTag=TorpedoBear, platform=PC], 
LeaderBoard [win=1, lose=0, gameName=NUPI, gamerTag=GreenPanda, platform=AN], 
LeaderBoard [win=0, lose=1, gameName=NUPI, gamerTag=GreenPanda, platform=AN]]
```

into:

```
LeaderBoard [win=1, lose=1, gameName=QUFI, gamerTag=Ithroeann, platform=IO]
LeaderBoard [win=2, lose=0, gameName=CODE, gamerTag=Cirronith, platform=PS]
```

etc...

I can't figure out how to do this.

Comment: I don't understand how you got that new `List`

Comment: Sorry what do you mean new list?

Comment: The "into:" part with only 2 elements

Comment: 1HeyMan1: He doesn't understand the expected result set. Incognito: there's an "etc..." there!

Comment: oh thats what i want it to look like after it is combined. Sorry should have been more clear

Comment: What is your expectation for GamerTag:VolcanoBrawler because the gameName is Unique for them. So do you wanna treat them as different records??

Comment: yes it would combine into 3 diffrent records: qufi, nupi, and code(game names)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can I start you off with some pseudocode?

```
// create an empty output array list
// for each element in the input array list
//     attempt to add it to the output
//     if the output already contains an element for this gamer tag, game name, etc
//         update that element, adding to the win/loss count
//     else
//         add a new record with this win/loss count
```

EDIT1: Okay, expanding slightly:

```
ArrayList<LeaderBoard> output = new ArrayList<LeaderBoard>();
:outer
for (LeaderBoard i : input) {
    for (LeaderBoard o : output) {
        if (i.gameName.equals(o.gameName)
            && i.gamerTag.equals(o.gamerTag)
            && i.platform.equals(o.platform)) {
            o.win += i.win;
            o.lose += i.lose;
            break outer;
        }
    }
    output.add(i);
}
return output;
```

EDIT2: And if you don't want to use a labelled break:

```
ArrayList<LeaderBoard> output = new ArrayList<LeaderBoard>();
for (LeaderBoard i : input) {
    boolean shouldAdd = true;
    for (LeaderBoard o : output) {
        if (i.gameName.equals(o.gameName)
            && i.gamerTag.equals(o.gamerTag)
            && i.platform.equals(o.platform)) {
            o.win += i.win;
            o.lose += i.lose;
            shouldAdd = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (shouldAdd) {
        output.add(i);
    }
}
return output;
```

Comment: Get the object, add to the numbers. It's by reference, remember!

Comment: Sorry but what does :outer mean?

Comment: It's for a labelled break. That may be a contentious addition, I'll add an alternative :)

Comment: Hey man thanks a lot this works, but i had to used the .equals() operator instead of the ==

Answer (score 1):

You could do it manually like Luke has suggested (good answer, +1).

Or you could create a HashMap of LeaderBoard objects, with the key being the gamerTag, and the value being the current LeaderBoard object.

Normal HashMaps only allow one value per key, and it would make them very quick to lookup, and easy to update.

Comment: Stop it you :) To expand on this, the logic is kinda similar; have an output HashMap (not an ArrayList this time), and for each input, check if it exists in the output, and update/add accordingly. You'll have to check the documentation for the HashMap for this.